# How to display icons without alteration in an ImageButton/ImageView?

Tags: android, image, icons

in my app, I have buttons with icons. The icons are provided as PNG images in the three densities in drawable-ldpi-v4/, drawable/ and drawable-hdpi-v4/. Here's a sample:

[image: Original icons]

Each icon is displayed in an ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton style="@style/Shortcut" android:id="@+id/open_button"
        android:src="@drawable/shortcut_open" android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>
```

Where the `Shortcut` style is:

```
<style name="Shortcut">
    <item name="android:layout_width">65dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dp</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shortcut_background</item>
</style>
```

However, on certain devices/platform versions, certain icons get altered, blurred or something. I'm not sure that it's scaling, it's more like a rendering bug I think. I have tried to disable anti aliasing on the BitmapDrawable, but that didn't help.

As shown on the image below, on Android 2.1 LDPI, one icon gets broken/cropped, and on both Android 1.6 MDPI and Android 2.1 HDPI an extra line seems to be randomly added at the bottom of the icon (look closely).

[image: Rendered icons]

In the manifest, I have an empty `<supports-screens />` as recommended in the docs about [supporting multiple screens in legacy apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#strategies). Adding `anyDensity="true"` doesn't help.

Apparently, as of Froyo, things get better as you can see on the image above. But how can I solve this on Android <= 2.1?

Comment: instead of setting it in the background, you should put it in the source to avoid scaling.

Comment: The icons are not in the background, they are in the src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not use explicit sizes (even when expressed as dip) for the buttons, but let the system do it for you.

Use

```
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/SpeakButton"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Also it may be that you are falling into the "dip" vs. "dp" trap that others have reported, where documentation says that they are synonymous, but using "dip" made stuff work as intended.

Comment: I need the buttons (the background) to have a fixed size with the icon centered. And there's no issue with the button size. I am talking about the icons getting altered, not about the button size.

Comment: Alright, I consider this to be workaround but it does work. In order to obtain a fixed button size, I have added some padding into all PNGs so that each icon is now 32x32dp, plus some extra padding in the style. And now indeed, using wrap_content, the icons are displayed properly on all devices and versions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case but you can check if you are not running into the bugs mentioned in this [Google I/O talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/casting-wide-net-android-devices.html). I still have to wrap my head around it but I think it's worth having a look if you are targeting platforms from 1.5 to 2.0.